# jQuery :contains(regex)?

Tags: jquery, regex, selector, contains

Is it possible to have a jQuery selector where the :contains() is a regular expression?

I need to select an element where the innerHTML contains something findable through regex?

I know it's a short question. My apologies.

```
var t = $("#id a:containsRegex("/[0-9]/g")"); // Doesn't work
```

Comment: Use `.filter()`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try ,

```
var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]"); // expression here

$("#id a").filter(function () {
    return regex.test($(this).text()); 
});
```

Comment: @Pilot using `innerText` is wrong. Use `$(this).text()` instead.

Comment: @Tomalak Updated..`innerText` is only valid for block elements ? M I right Master

Comment: fyi you can use `var regex = /[0-9]/;` to make it more readable

Comment: @Pilot No, `innerText`is simply a proprietary DOM extension once invented by Microsoft. It should not be used as the default way to get text from an element, all modern browsers support the W3C standard `textContent` property.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for such a valuable comment..Much appreciated.

Comment: just for others' reference `filter` is a jquery function not a native array filter function which i was mistaking it for.