# Find element in which regex matches using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Is there a way to find element using regex to search in its text. So for example, if element p has word kobra in it then jquery selector returns the list of those elements optionally wrapping matched words in span element.

I need it to create search functionality. Basically there is a li based list. User enters a term, then all elements are gotten using that regex to element selector, then upon clicking next user is scrolled to that position.

Comment: `$('element:contains(kobra)')` http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ Watch out with the word kobra. GI:JOE will come.

Comment: my mind just got blown...

Comment: i found somethin similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929862/jquery-containsregex

Answer (score 3):

If nothing fancy is needed, based upon your question, user enters a search term, search term is displayed: use jQuery's `contains` selector, no regex is needed:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
 $('element:contains(kobra)')
```

Comment: This will probably suit this particular person's need, but won't work for regex.

Comment: Yes i dont think i need regex afterall

Answer (score 1):

Use a jQuery selector that matches all the elements you want to search in, then run your regex query on each of them. Here's some rough pseudocode:

```
$('.myParagraphs').each(function() {
  var obj = $(this);
  if (obj.text().matches(myRegexp)) {
    //code to scroll to that element
  }
});
```

Comment: will this work, aren't you searching regex in jquery element not in its text value

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot .text(). Fixed it

Comment: but this code will result in page being scrolled to last matched element, as over each iteration of loop it will be scrolled to element that matches.

Comment: If you add a break; inside of that if statement, then the loop will stop executing after the first match.